# play_hires.inoでの再生時に発生するノイズ

Tags: spresense

spresenseを利用して96kHzサンプリングレートにて18kHzから48kHzに遷移するチャープ信号を再生すると、画像のようなノイズが発生してしまいます。緑で囲まれた部分が所望の再生信号なのですが、それ以外の音声が発生しているのですが、これを修正する方法はありますでしょうか？
テストはspresenseのメインボードに、公式の拡張ボードまたはB-stem PDA01を接続しイヤホンジャックから再生しています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

確かに、96kHz/24bitにはノイズがありますね。
192kHzではノイズは載らないようですし、16bitでもノイズが出ていないようです。

出力を48kHzまで出したい場合、理論値では96kHzサンプリングでも出せるのですが、折り返しなどが酷く、
所望の波形になりにくいので、192kHzで出力してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 192kHzで再生しましたが、同じ症状でした。
一応、二台でテストしましたがハードで当たり外れがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど。自分の思っている現象と異なるのかもしれません。HWの問題でしたら、メーカに問い合わせてみるのもよいかもしれませんね。

Comment: ちなみになのですが、今回のRev.2.2.0のリリースで、
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/releases/tag/v2.2.0 

[Audio] サンプリングレート96kHzでビット長24bitのWAV再生時にノイズが発生する問題を修正しました。

とあり、実際に確認したところ、自分の気になるノイズはなくなっていました。